# How to configure PullApprove to send requests to a subset of a team that can submit approvals?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request, github-codereviews

I'm using PullApprove v3 for GitHub PRs. I have a larger team `general-team` and a smaller team `specific-team`. `specific-team` is a subset of `general-team`.

I want to allow PR approvals from anyone on `general-team` but only send requests to `specific-team` to avoid spamming `general-team`.

I found in the [PullApprove documentation](https://www.pullapprove.com/docs/v3/config/reviewers/#reviewers-that-dont-want-review-requests) that I can prefix a team with `~` to exclude them from receiving requests. My `.pullapprove.yml` looks like this:

```
version: 3

groups:
  code:
    reviews:
      required: 1
      request: 2
    reviewers:
      teams:
      - specific-team
      - ~general-team
```

But because `specific-team` is a subset of `general-team`, they are marked unavailable and no requests go out. How can I send requests to `specific-team`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people use [optional groups](https://www.pullapprove.com/docs/v3/config/type/#optional) + [overrides](https://www.pullapprove.com/docs/v3/config/overrides/) (and [reviewed_for](https://www.pullapprove.com/docs/v3/config/reviews/#reviewed_for)) to do this. Something like this:

```yaml
version: 3

overrides:
- if: len(groups.approved.include("global-approvers")) == 1
  status: success
  explanation: 'Passing as globally approved by global approvers'

groups:
  code:
    reviews:
      required: 1
      request: 2
    reviewers:
      teams:
      - specific-team
  
  global-approvers:
    type: optional
    reviews:
      request: 0
      required: 1
      reviewed_for: required
    reviewers:
      teams:
      - general-team
```